# How to make the quick-find algorithm and return a list set as the result using a class in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I would like to make a quick-find algorithm using a python class. I am unsure how to return the final data set. Where the connection variables are set as below, I would like to return the final result:

```
N = 10
connections = [(4,3), (3,8)]
result = [0,1,2,8,8,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The class code is:

```
class QuickFind(object):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.lst = list(range(N))

    def union(self, a, b):
        old = self.lst[a]
        new = self.lst[b]
            for ind in self.lst:
            if ind == old:
                self.lst[ind] = new

# execution code is:
for i, j in connections:
    QuickFind(10).union(i, j)

... some code ...

print(result)
```

Comment: What should the QuickFind algorithm return?

Comment: The result should be a list of [0,1,2,8,8,5,6,7,8,9] as the connections are [(4,3), (3,8)].

Comment: This is not the quick-find algorithm; you could call it slow-find.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently creating a `QuickFind` instance for each iteration of your loop over `connections`, but then it throws away the object afterwards. If you want to have all the `union` calls done on the same object, and you want to be able to see the results afterwards, you need to change that so that there's just one object created, and that you store a reference to it in a variable.

Try something like this:

```
qf = QuickFind(10)

for i, j in connections:
    qf.union(i, j)

...

result = qf.lst
print(result) # or combine these lines into print(qf.lst)
```

There's also an issue with the implementation of `union`. The `ind` variable you're getting from your loop is a bit misleadingly named, as it's not an index, but a value from the list. During the `if` statement, you treat it correctly as a value (comparing it to `old`, which is also a value), but in the assignment afterwards, you're using it as an index instead. I think you really do need both a value and an index, so I'd suggest rewriting the loop to use `enumerate` so that you'll have each one when you need it:

```
for i, val in enumerate(self.lst):
    if val == old:
        self.lst[i] = new
```

Comment: After running the code, the result has only the final `union` call, returning   `[0, 1, 2, 8, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Ah, there was a second subtle error. I've updated my answer.